# Building Angular 6 portal from multiple repos

Tags: angular, artifactory, portal

I am trying to build an Angular6 portal, which includes 4-5 existing Angular6 dashboards in different stages of development (some are new, some already in production, but all are in active development).

I spoke to several Angular gurus.  Some suggested to use Nrwl NX (but that won't work, since I am in large bank, and they don't have monorepo, and it will be extremely hard to convince and years to spend in transition).

Others suggested iFrame, but said they tried and it is not worth it (hard with multiple browsers, not responsive, limited child-parent communication, limited routing).

I have seen that CLI [approach](http://%20https://medium.com/disney-streaming/combining-multiple-angular-applications-into-a-single-one-e87d530d6527) works, but since all dashboards are in active development, I can not put their code inside the portal, it is too restrictive. In addition, some of them are deployed as standalone today.
Is there a way to make sub-apps external to the portal (lets say same level apps in single repo) ?

Can Elements help?  (CDK portal feature seems not to work)

Another question is what if I need to pass some parameters from portal to a dashboard (let's say filter results to display),
how can that be done?

Please advise.

TIA,
Oleg.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of these options:

## Option 1

The simplest way to accomplish this would be to have 1 single extra Angular application that acts like a central hub for the 5 dashboards. This app would have 5 links to each of the dashboards. This can be done in a way that is transparent to the user, they would just notice that going from one app to the other causes a full page refresh.

For example, in the following image one can have the `Tags` link go to the "Tags dashboard" and the `Users` link go to the "Users dashboard". The user would notice where the HTML is coming from:

[image]

## Option 2

You can use the solution from [that link you shared](https://medium.com/disney-streaming/combining-multiple-angular-applications-into-a-single-one-e87d530d6527), in conjunction with [Git Submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules). A submodule is a git repo inside of a git repo, each one modifiable independently. So each team can make updates to their own dashboard in their own git repo. You would create a new angular app in a new git repo, and add the other repos as submodules. Only when you want to do a release of the whole app you would pull their latest `master` branch into the parent repo, and release from there.

Comment: Thank you for interesting answer. What if the dashboards are in Artifactory (and main portal is in another repo), would that help?   Is it possible to launch such sub-app from the portal?  How?    Please advise.   Oleg.

Comment: @olegkon Iḿ not familiar with Artifcatory. Is it a host for Git repos?